# PHP regex (or better alternative) for array of coordinates

Tags: php, regex

I have an array of coordinates in a string from a query string that looks like this:

```
[[50.864750,-1.230874],[50.870490,-1.224007]]
```

I have tried many times and failed to create a regular expression that would split how I need it. Below is the format I need both of these coordinates after the regular expression to take place:

```
$coordinateSet[0] = "50.864750 -1.230874";
$coordinateSet[1] = "50.870490 -1.224007";
```

Is regex the best solution or is there a better alternative?

Comment: @flec How is that going to help anyone answer the question? Or is it just to prove you're not doing my homework?

Comment: @jskidd3 That's how this site works. You show where you fail and people help you correct. Not you state what you need and people do it for you...

Comment: Since it's not what you're asking, I'm leaving this as a comment: Instead of using a regular expression (that tends to be hard to read and maintain), you could use `json_decode()` on this format; then an `array_map()` with an `implode(' ', ...)` function (anonymous or otherwise) to get the exact result you need.

Comment: @pinkgothic That sounds like a much better solution, if I altered the question to be less specific could you please leave that as an answer?

Comment: Happy to. :) Give me a tic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your input format looks like it can be interpreted as JSON, I'd recommend using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) instead of a regular expression (given regexen tend to be a headache to read and maintain).

`json_decode()` on the string you mentioned would give you:

```
array(
   array(
       50.864750,
       -1.230874,
   ),
   array(
       50.870490,
       -1.224007,
   ),
)
```

(For error handling, you probably want to make sure `json_decode()` did not return `null` - that would denote a syntax error in your input format.)

Then, if your output format is specific, you could use an [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) with an [`implode(' ', ...)`](http://php.net/implode) function (anonymous or otherwise) to get the exact result you need.